# how to change table row class when checked based on same value attributes

Tags: php, jquery

We have multiple line items on some orders and others that only have one. I only want one checkbox per similar order number. When the box is checked I need to highlight every line that has that order number. Of course the order number will always be different. What I am doing is putting the order number in the td as a value for every similar row. The order number is also a value of the checkbox input. So if I checked the 1000002 check box it would highlight both rows that same order number. I am new to jQuery and I found some jquery that highlight the closest column, but I know this will have to be changed alot to get it to do what I need it too.

```
<tr class="danger"  value="1000005">
    <td><input name="checkOrder[1000005][ord_no]" value=" 1000005" type="checkbox" class="checkOrder" id="checkOrder"></td>

    <td>   1000005 </td>
    <td>  65734COM </td>
    <td> dummy product1</td>
    <td>$565.00</td>

    <td>$0 </td>
    <td>$565</td></tr>


<tr class="danger" value="1000002">
    <td><input name="checkOrder[1000002][ord_no]" value=" 1000002" type="checkbox" class="checkOrder" id="checkOrder"></td>

    <td>   1000002 </td>
    <td>  54354534 </td>
    <td> dummy product2</td>
    <td>$900.00</td>

    <td>$1080.46 </td>
    <td>$-180.46</td></tr>

<tr class="danger" value="1000002">
    <td></td>
    <td> 1000002</td>
    <td>  087373 </td>
    <td> dummy product3</td>
    <td>$750.00</td>
    <td>$919.00 </td>
    <td>$-169</td></tr>
```

My jQuery

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
            var myName = $(this).attr("value");
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                if(myName == )
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass("primary");
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("danger");

            }
            else{
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("primary");
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass("danger");

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking for the closest `tr` (row) , not the closest `td` (column).

Use `$(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight");`

Also, you need to find first the rows that you need to change:

Get the ordernumber

`var ordernum = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').attr('value');`

Then find all rows in the table that have the same ordernumber

```
$('table td[value="' + ordernum + '"]').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).closest('tr').addClass('danger');
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('.checkOrder').click(function() {
    var ordernum = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').attr('value');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('table td[value="' + ordernum + '"]').each(function(i, v) {
        $(v).closest('tr').addClass('danger');
      });
    } else {
      $('table td[value="' + ordernum + '"]').each(function(i, v) {
        $(v).closest('tr').removeClass('danger');
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="checkOrder[1000005][ord_no]" value=" 1000005" type="checkbox" class="checkOrder" id="checkOrder">
      </td>
      <td value="1000005">1000005</td>
      <td>65734COM</td>
      <td>dummy product1</td>
      <td>$565.00</td>

      <td>$0</td>
      <td>$565</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="checkOrder[1000002][ord_no]" value=" 1000002" type="checkbox" class="checkOrder" id="checkOrder">
      </td>
      <td value="1000002">1000002</td>
      <td>54354534</td>
      <td>dummy product2</td>
      <td>$900.00</td>
      <td>$1080.46</td>
      <td>$-180.46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td value="1000002"></td>
      <td>1000002</td>
      <td>087373</td>
      <td>dummy product3</td>
      <td>$750.00</td>
      <td>$919.00</td>
      <td>$-169</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I changed my question a little, but it looks like this is going to work. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I saw you figured out the `tr` already. Anyways, no worries. You're welcome.